# MVC GlobalFilters not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this

```
public class ExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Exception exception = context.Exception;
        if (!(exception is HttpException))
        {
           Trace.TraceError("ExceptionFilter: " + ExceptionUtilities.GetFullExceptionMessage(exception));
           Trace.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

and this in global.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new Filters.ExceptionFilter());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

but when I trigger an error by creating a dangerous request like this

> example.com/dsfgds:dfgd

I get an exception:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (:)

and the filter doesn't fire and the breakpoint inside doesn't get hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're registering an `IExceptionFilter` with MVC, and as such it will only capture unhandled exceptions that were raised within an MVC Action (and I think maybe other MVC filters? Don't quote me on that). But the error about a potentially dangerous request is an ASP.NET error, the request never made it to MVC, so the MVC error filter never gets called. Likewise, any IIS level errors would also not be handled by this. For non-MVC errors you still need to monitor the `Application_OnError` event. Or in the case of exception handlers like Elmah, let it monitor the event for you.